# How to select column value from another database referenced by field inside same query?

Tags: mysql, reference

suppose that i have the following table in my database called 'central':

| id | Name | DB | customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | A1 | 1 |
| 2 | Marley | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Irene | A2 | 2 |

The customer column references to the 'Customers' table which is inside of **another database**.

**IMPORTANT**: the database names A1 and A2 are only examples. There will be hundreds of separate databases containing a Customers table.
The central.DB column is a reference to which database to use when selecting the CustomerName from inside of the select statement that you see below the following example databases.

An example from the Customers table inside of Database 'A1':

| id | Customer | CustomerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C001 | Asta housing |
| 2 | C002 | Jack's |

An example from the Customers table inside of Database 'A2':

| id | Customer | CustomerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D900 | Mo's |
| 2 | D901 | Humpries paints |

I can't figure out how to do something like this and maybe it's not possible at all:

```
SELECT Central.id, Central.Name, (central.DB).Customers.CustomerName 
FROM central, (central.DB).Customers.
```

Or maybe use a join to do this?

Either way, the query result should should be:

| id | Name | CustomerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Asta housing |
| 2 | Marley | NULL |
| 3 | Irene | Humpries paints |

Maybe this isn't possible and the result is that i must do it with php? But i'd rather not do this as central.DB could reference potentially hundreds of databases and that will possibly be rather expensive (a lot of calls to the referenced databases).

(I can't change the setup of using a central database and the other separate databases)

Is it possible to reference to another database(table) when the name of that database is inside of the result set?

Comment: *The customer column references to the 'Customers' table which is inside of another database.* Does all 3 databases are in the same MySQL server instance?

Comment: For now both the central and A1, A2, etc. etc. databases are in the same instance, but later on they could be in separate instances (which complicates my question, i know)

Answer (score 0):

**If both databases are at the same server(MySQL Instance) you can just prefix the tables with the database name.**

```
SELECT C.id, C.Name, CU.CustomerName FROM database_1.Central AS C LEFT JOIN database_2.Customers AS CU
```

**Make sure that the user logged in has permission to access both databases.**

Comment: There are 3 databases totally - A1, A2 and *suppose that i have the following table in **my database** called 'central'*

Comment: I think it would not create any problem to join 3 databases if you have permission to access all database

Comment: Thanks Habib. No permission problems at all, so don't worry about that fact. And i've updated the question to better reflect the fact that A1 and A2 are only examples and that there will be hundreds of databases besides of the central database (which acts as a central hub)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t0.id, 
       t0.name, 
       COALESCE(t1.CustomerName, t2.CustomerName) CustomerName
FROM my_database.central t0
LEFT JOIN A1.Customers t1 ON (t0.customer, t0.DB) = (t1.ID, 'DB1')
LEFT JOIN A2.Customers t2 ON (t0.customer, t0.DB) = (t2.ID, 'DB2')
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem for me is: the database from which the CustomerName must be selected is the central.DB value.   So central.DB points to the database and the query must use that to not only retrieve values from the central database, but also the related CustomerName from the database central.DB pointed to. If i look at your query, you join the A1 and A2 tables and that's fine, IF you know which databases to join. But you only know the right database to join when the select from central retrieved DB column....so your query isn't working for my situation :-(

Comment: I've edited my question to better reflect the fact that databases A1 and A2 are only examples and that central.DB references to a databases from which the CustomerName must be selected. Normally i would just join the Customers table if it was inside of the central database. But because central.DB dictates from which database the CustomerName should be retrieved, i can't. Or at least: i don't now how to.

Comment: @Dave33 *IF you know which databases to join. But you only know the right database to join when the select from central retrieved DB column* Only dynamic SQL (prepared statement) may help in this case.

Comment: hmm yeah that might be a good way to go. Will try that. Also trying to rewrite my query in such a way that i also get what i want.